# Read a csv file in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm getting into TypeScript as a way to write simple utility programs, meant to be run on the command line. There are a bunch of basic questions I have, maybe someone can give me pointers.

1. I am assuming that I will run the app by a command like: `$ node myapp.js`
2. If I want to run it by `$ myapp.js` I need a shebang line in the js, but I can't see how to have that flow from the .ts file, so I have to post edit the js file, right?
3. How do I just open a text file from a local path within TypeScript? Where do I look for the right incantation?
4. And once I have the text file open I have to process it as a cvs. I found a library called node-cvs but I am not sure how to connect the dots.

Comment: It should be CSV (Comma Separated Values) not CVS in the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. I am assuming that I will run the app by a command like: `$ node myapp.js`

Yes. TypeScript compiles to JavaScript.

> 2. If I want to run it by `$ myapp.js` I need a shebang line in the js, but I can't see how to have that flow from the .ts file, so I have to post edit the js file, right?

No. Take a look at my workaround : https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6674#issuecomment-108132800

> 3. How do I just open a text file from a local path within typescript? Where do I look for the right incantation?

`fs.readFile` in node. You can use it in typescript (and even provide type safety using `node.d.ts` : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts

> 4. And once I have the text file open I have to process it as a cvs. I found a library called node-cvs but I am not sure how to connect the dots.

You can just do `require('node-cvs')` same as javascript

Comment: The link to node.d.ts is broken

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do something like:

```
/// <reference path="node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="a-type-definition-for-node-csv.d.ts" />

import fs = require('fs');
import parse = require('node-csv');

var parser = parse({delimiter: ','}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/fs_read.csv').pipe(parser);
```